# Netbeans mysql , I have button called "New Record"

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL called Student with PK called Rollno.
Using Netbeans JFrame Form and DB MySQL.  I have a button called "New Record".

When end-users click on the button "New Record", I need to have the next available Rollno
inserted into the "jTextField1" that is for "Rollno" in the JFrame Form.
what I have so far is:

```java
jTextField1 = new JTextField();

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", "root", "mypass");
    System.out.println("Connected");

    String query = "Select max(rollno) as max from student ";
    //System.out.println("SQL IS");
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        int num = rs.getInt("max");
        int inc = num + 1;
        jTextField1.setText(valueOf(inc));

    }
} catch (Exception a) {
}
```

Please advise,

Thx-Abrahim

Comment: This won't work if you have multiple users accessing it at the same time, you have a race condition.

Comment: _"Please advise"_ is not a question. What is the problem you're trying to address?

Comment: I am trying to get the next available "Rollno" which is the PK and get inserted into the jTextfield1 which is the textField in the form, but my script does not insert the next Rollno into the jTextfield1. Did I clarify my question to you?

Comment: Why you want to retrieve `rollno`? Should it be used for the next entry you want to create?

Comment: Yes, I need it to be used for the next entry for end-users who want to create a new record. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to do it this way. For example you'd loose the ability for multiple users to use your application.

In case the primary key is a normal integer I'd just let the database assign that value for you.

This is quite esay by adding the [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute to your primary key.